# Share mutable state between multiple invocations of a React component with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, react-hooks

I'd like to create a `withPromise`, that works like this:

```js
import {useState, withEffect} from "react";

function usePromise(promise, default=null) {
    // This state variable will hold the value of our promise.
    // We allow the user to pass in a default value that'l be returned
    // as long as the promise hasn't been resolved.
    let value, setValue = useState(default);

    // Ensure that this is only re-run when the promise changes.
    withEffect(() => {
        promise.then(setValue)
    }, [promise])

    return value;
}
```

This works well if the promise parameter never changes, but I'd like it to adapt in case a new promise is passed in, because at this point, it might lead to a race condition.

1. `promise1` is passed to `usePromise`
2. `promise2` is passed to `usePromis-e`
3. `promise2` is resolved, setting the value to `value2`
4. `promise1` is resolved, setting the value to `value1`

In this sequence of events, the value of the new promise, is overwritten by the value of the old promise, which resolved later.

But since promises aren't cancelable, I don't see a way to check in the callback of a promise whether a new promise has been passed in while it was waiting to be resolved.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

useEffect can return a function for teardown logic. While you can't cancel a promise, you can set a flag which you then check when the promise resolves to abort the callback. For example, something like the following:

```
function usePromise(promise, default=null) {
  let [value, setValue] = useState(default);

  useEffect(() => {
    let cancelled = false;
    promise.then((result) => {
      if (!cancelled) {
        setValue(result);
      }
    })
    return () => cancelled = true;
  }, [promise])

  return value;
}
```

Comment: Actually depending on what the promise does, it might be cancellable. For instance if you're making a fetch request, it can be cancelled. See https://medium.com/@bgdam/the-abortcontroller-and-aborting-fetch-requests-in-javascript-1761c6d3a806 for details.